# How to add a new page in PHP?

Tags: php, ftp, unzip

I am doing a system of upload the archives and extract for ftp but as php dont have function "ftp_unzip", I must do an archive to extract inside host.

```
<?php
//Upload the image file to the server

$ftp_server = 'luis.habboproject.net';
$ftp_user_name= 'login';
$ftp_user_pass = 'senha'; 

echo $_FILES['userfile']['name'];

$source_file= "archive.zip";
$destination_file="/public_html/archive.zip";

$source_file2= "oi.php";
$destination_file2="/public_html/oi.php";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server); 

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass); 

// check connection
if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) { 
echo "FTP connection has failed!";
echo "Attempted to connect to $ftp_server for user $ftp_user_name"; 
exit; 
} else {
echo "Connected to $ftp_server, for user $ftp_user_name";
}

// turn passive mode on
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);

// upload the file
$upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file, $source_file, FTP_BINARY); 
$upload2 = ftp_put($conn_id, $destination_file2, $source_file2, FTP_BINARY); 


// check upload status
if (!$upload) { 

} else{
// Code to Acting a page http://luis.habboproject.net/oi.php to extract the archive.zip in a host


}
// close the FTP stream 
ftp_close($conn_id);

?>
```

I want to know if there is some function in php or javascript, that have same result of a "submit button", but without click. In other words, I want to execute the archive to active the extractor.

Comment: Sorry, this place is English language only. Others want to read questions and answers too.

Comment: I am going do a question in english.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to that! It probably would make sense to delete this one here...

Comment: Non English language used in the description.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not written in english.

Comment: i put in english, sorry everybody.